# Array in Array in Angularjs with Data Coming from Server

Tags: angularjs

I have a column named "project_manager_names" in Workbench MYSQL. I am trying to bring a few of data in array of that column. Here are the codes which I think are correct, but don't fetch any data and the view freezes:

```
<dd>
  <div ng-repeat-start="managers in project_data"></div>
  <div ng-repeat="name in managers.project_manager_name">{{name}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat-end><br /></div>
</dd>
```

and the controller.js:

```
function ProjectCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout, $state, $stateParams) {

$http.get('../crud/projects_read.php').then(function(response){
    $scope.projects = response.data;
    $scope.project_data = $scope.projects[$stateParams.id]
    });
};
```

and the "project_manager_name" from the Server:

```
{ name:"Mike" }, {name:"Jenny"}, {name:"James"}
```

I MANUALLY INPUT THE DATA LIKE THAT IN WORKBENCH DATABASE. Maybe this could be wrong?

How can I make the above code to be working in order to bring the array NAME from PROJECT_MANAGER_NAME from the table?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `ng-repeat` on the element you want to be repeated. The `manager in managers` will look through each of the elements in `managers` and assign it to the `manager` variable. You can then access the column in the results with `{{ manager.product_manager_name }}`. You can access the `name` element as `manager.product_manager_name.name`.

**Controller**

```
$scope.managers = [
  { name: 'manager 1', product_manager_name: { name: 'mike' } },
  { name: 'manager 2', product_manager_name: { name: 'joe' } },
];
```

**HTML Partial**

```
<div ng-repeat="manager in managers">
  <div>{{ manager.product_manager_name.name }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your support!!